# Static member '<top/center/bottom>' cannot be used on instance of type 'Alignment'

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, swiftui

This compiling error in SwiftUI is usually not about 'Alignment' or the Stack where it's pointing at. Rather it's like a standard message for when a method call within the stack is receiving an incorrect type, for example when you passed a `Double` instead of a `CGFloat` somewhere.

I hope this will be fixed soon by Apple, but in the meanwhile, have anyone found a compiler setting (or some other trick) so that you easier can track down the actual problem?

This bug is beginning to be quite annoying.

Comment: Updating Xcode will help you with this specific issue. (ignoring Xcode issues)

Answer (score 1):

These misleading errors are due to the compiler's inability to effectively type-check your whole expression. The good news is that Swift 5.2 will include a [new diagnostics architecture](https://swift.org/blog/new-diagnostic-arch-overview/) that should help out a lot, and enable much more specific and actionable error messages.

In the meantime, the only real workaround is to comment lines out one-by-one, until it will compile. Then, you can examine that line to try and figure out what it's complaining about.

Comment: I would add that decomposing view building hierarchy into smaller parts from the very beginning of design allows to decrease number of unclear/mis-located errors drastically.